# Just Wondering if I Should Use Him or Them?

Tags: pronouns

Is it:

> Nobody was ever there for me when I needed **him**.

or

> Nobody was ever there for me when I needed **them**.

Answer (score 2):

Since "nobody" contains no information about the persons' genders the word to use is **"them"**. "**They/them**" can also be used to refer to someone in the third person singular form:

> **They** were never there for me when I needed **them**

Without context this sentence could refer to either one or multiple people.

Comment: Surely: **Nobody contains any information about the person's gender.... ** Nobody being singular and permitting only a single gender (even in this post modern world!)

Comment: I meant the word "nobody" itself does not contain any information about the gender of the people it is describing. I'm not sure what you meant.

Comment: I didn't express myself clearly. The word **nobody** is singular. It contains no information **about the person's gender** (singular) rather than **the persons' genders** (plural). Whereas the pronouns **they** and **them** are used both in the plural and to refer to a single person of unknown gender (as you illustrate), **nobody** must be followed by the singular possessive (person's) rather than the plural (persons').